# Pause Music when click item Listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview(3 item)

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            switch (arg2) {
            case 0:

                LoadMp3(getUrl[0]);

                break;
            case 1:

                LoadMp3(getUrl[1]);

                break;
            case 2:

                LoadMp3(getUrl[2]);

                break;
            case 3:

                LoadMp3(getUrl[3]);

                break;
```

I want play music when click item(Example:item1),and pause music on item 1 when click different item(Item 2) and play music on Item 2.Please Help me!

```
    public void LoadMp3(String name) {
    try {
        m = new MediaPlayer();

        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = MainActivity.this.getAssets()
                .openFd(name);
        m.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        descriptor.close();
        m.prepare();
        m.start();
        m.setLooping(false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle error here..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check create another button `clickListener` write the condition like if it `isplaying()` then `pause();`

```
 if(m.isPlaying()){
    m.pause();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if(null==m){
    m = new MediaPlayer();
}else if(m.isPlaying()){
    m.pause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try following code

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {

           LoadMp3(getUrl[arg2]);
         }
    }


     public void LoadMp3(String name) {
      try {
         if(m!=null){
            if(m.isPlaying()){
              m.stop();
              m=null;
           }    
        }
        m = new MediaPlayer();

        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = MainActivity.this.getAssets()
                .openFd(name);
        m.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        descriptor.close();
        m.prepare();
        m.start();
        m.setLooping(false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle error here..
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a global instance of MediaPlayer

```
    if(m.Playing()){
       m.Pause();
       LoadMp3(nameofFile);
    }
```